# How can I deal with null environmental variables in my minishell?

Tags: c, shell, unix, environment-variables, expansion

I'm making a minishell in C, I'm at the point that I'm accounting for environmental variables. I take the original input line from the user, and pass it to a function:

```
int expand(char *orig, char *new, int newsize)
```

Where new is a fixed length char array. I loop through orig until I find ${ and then use getenv to find the value of the variable. If there is in fact a value, I simply copy it to new. However, I'm having problems when there is no value, and getenv returns null.

My teacher told me to simply insert a null character, however this doesn't make any sense to me, and I think he meant something different. If I were to insert a null character into orig, then when I parsed it into arguments, it would think that null character marked the end of string, and wouldn't bother looking for any further arguments.

For example, if I entered a session like so:

```
echo ${USER} ${NOTHING} ${TERM}
```

Then:

```
orig = "echo ${USER} ${NOTHING} ${TERM}\0"
```

and

```
new = "echo my_user_name \0 xterm\0"
```

The output would be:

```
my_user_name
```

Because it would consider my_user_name to be the last argument, seeing as there is a null terminator before it can read xterm into the argument list.

I know this is a vague question, but I figured some of you guys are pretty experienced in making minishells and know how this problem is typically addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps he meant insert a null string, i.e. replace the variable with nothing. That's what /bin/sh does.

```
$ echo "hi $joe how are you"
hi  how are you
```

The null character is the one with value 0. It's commonly written as `'\0'`. As you know it is the C end-of-string marker.

The null string is also called the empty string. It's `""`. In C it's represented by a 0-length, 1-byte character array, as in:

```
char str[1] = {'\0'};
```

But conceptually it's the unique string that contains no characters.

Personally, I prefer to call it the empty string rather than null string. Null is such an overused word. Null character. Null pointers.

Comment: He didn't mean that, because if you do that in a UNIX shell it won't have the extra space in there.


I'm talking about pre-argument list. This is just processing the original string into an expanded string. Replacing the variable with nothing will simply omit it form existence.

Comment: @Scriptonaut Yes, omitting it from existence is what real shells do.

Comment: @Scriptonaut The reason there are two spaces is because of the double quotes.

Comment: @Scriptonaut Notice that he wrote null string rather than null character. His description is extremely terse, but it is correct. Fortunately or unfortunately, that's the kind of documentation you get on UNIX systems. Technically correct, absolutely precise, and not a single word wasted on fluffery like explaining what the heck that means.

Comment: I had a suspicion that there was a difference between null string and null character.

If you don't mind, would you like me to an explanation or give me a very short synopsis?

Comment: @Scriptonaut I added an explanation to my answer.